# How to find a normal vector from a vectorial equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have the following vectorial equation

- $[x,y] = [1,1]+k[2,-1]$

The question asks me to find a normal vector of this line represented by this equation.  However, I only know that we can find direction vector from this equation which is [2,-1].

So how can I found the normal director?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want a vector which is normal to $[2,-1]$. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I am not really sure. On my book it only says that we can use the vectorial equation to find "direction vector", and use the cartesian equation to find "normal vector". But it did not mention the other way

Comment: In general, two vectors $v,w$ are orthogonal if and only if $v\cdot w=0$, i.e. their dot product is zero. So, we want a vector $[x,y]$ such that $[2,-1]\cdot [x,y]=0$. This is the same as saying $2x-y=0$. So you just need to find a pair of real numbers $x$ and $y$ satisfying that equation.

Comment: So that is to say there is an infinite number of normal vector?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can try drawing a picture of the situation to see what's going on.

Comment: okay, sure thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal vector to that line is any orthogonal vector to $(2, -1)$. For example $(1, 2)$.